# Dragging UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I'm working on an iPhone application where I want to drag the table view (not the cells) upto a certain point in the screen. I have the tableview sitting in the bottom half of the screen and I have an image in the top-half.

When I scroll the table to see the rows below, the table should actually move up going above the image (y pos decreases and the height will increase). Table will go up until it fills the entire screen leaving a few pixels for the image and it docks there and from that point onwards, the table should scroll. Same behavior is expected for scrolling down as well.

This might sound a little weird but this is a new iOS pattern that's emerging.

I managed to do the first part using the code snippet below.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanForScrollView:)];
panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

- (void)handlePanForScrollView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

            CGPoint movement = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
            CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
            frame.origin.y += movement.y;
            if(frame.origin.y >= Y_OFFSET && frame.origin.y < self.original_frame.origin.y){
                frame.size.height -= movement.y;
                self.tableView.frame = frame;
                [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
            }
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:{
            //NSLog(@"End");
            break;
        }
        default:
            ;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is working fine and the table moves up and docks below the Y_OFFSET. But as you would have imagined, the table doesn't scroll any more.

So I tried this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if(self.tableView.frame.origin.y <= Y_OFFSET ||  self.tableView.frame.origin.y >= self.original_frame.origin.y){
        NSLog(@"Here");
        return YES;
    }   
    return NO;
}
```

"Here" message is getting printed on the console but the table doesn't scroll.

I even tried using the panGestureRecognizer for the UITableView instead of my UIPanGestureRecognizer.

```
self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanForScrollView:)
```

But now the table scrolls and moves up.

"I want the table not to scroll but to move until a certain point on the screen and then stop moving and start scrolling."

What's the best way to deal with this ?

Cheers

Comment: Are you not returning wrong value in `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`? It should be `return NO;` when table view is docked. Am I missing something?

Comment: Changing the values (YES / NO) doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you're doing it is fine.  You just need to stop the UIGestureRecognizer from handling any more touches after a certain point.  So what I would do (with the least amount of change to your existing code) is just override the delegate function:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

In that function, analyze the position of the table view and if the table view has reached a certain height already, return NO.  This will stop the UIPanGestureRecognizer from accepting the touch event and pass it up the chain, which should go straight to the UIScrollView of the table view.

Alternative, if I had the time to figure this out, I would try to accomplish this with the image as the table's header (self.tableView.tableHeaderView).  This way all of the scrolling is done within the the scrollview of the table and the table's frame doesn't have to move.  If you wanted to add some cool effects to the tableHeaderView, you could always override the UIScrollViewDelegate function `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and slightly shift the image in the header as the table scrolls up the initial half screen (this is the same effect that Path does).  However, this wouldn't allow you to peg the image at the very top of the table view... the entire image would scroll away.  Just my 2 cents. :)

Comment: That did fix my problem! Wohoo!

Comment: One more quick question @Mr. T - Is there anyway I will get the velocity (so that I can determine whether the swipe was up or down) in  shouldReceiveTouch method ? I tried velocityInView and checked velocity.y but it always returns 0.0

Comment: Hmm, that's exactly how I do it.  However, try this, in your call, pass in the tableview's superview.  So something like, CGPoint velocity = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender velocityInView:self.tableView.superview].  I think I had a problem in the past where I passed in the view itself to velocityInView and it didn't work correctly... Not sure if that's what's tripping you up, but worth a shot.  Good luck!

Comment: I tried with all the views but still velocity.y is 0.0 :( Once I dock the tableview to the top, I will have to move it down when the user scrolls down and hence I need to know if the scroll is happening upwards or downwards. Any other suggestions mate ?

Comment: This really should work.  Can you paste your handleRecognizer code as an edit to your questions above?

Comment: I split the logic to calculate things in the "Changed" state vs the "Ended" state differently.  When the state of the pan just changed, then I consider that a drag and I calculate the movement based on [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender translationInView:self.tableView.superview].  When the state of the pan has ended, I consider that a throw and I calculate the movement based on the direction + velocity using velocityInView.  If it's a "drag" state, try using translationInView instead of velocityInView... I think it's a more useful metric.  But regardless, paste some code above.

Comment: The problem with that approach is when the table is docked at the top, shouldReceiveTouch handler will return NO so as for the table to scroll. And when it returns NO, handlePanRecognizer won't be invoked. So I'm trying to find the direction of the scroll from shouldReceiveTouch handler and if the direction is downwards, then I will return NO and drag the tabe. If it's upwards, I will return YES and the table will scroll. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I ended up using the UITableView panGestureRecognizer and made few changes in the handlePan function.It's not perfect but looks fine for this release. Your answer was very close to resolving my problem and hence I'm accepting your answer. Thanks for your time mate! Cheers!

Comment: Jugs, if you got this working would you mind posting a completed code snippet?  I'm having the same problem here and would love to see a working version!

Answer (score 0):

If I rightly understand the question, the simplest solution is to programmatically set the tableView header to the desired image. (I think this is like what Path does for setting a location, with the exception that they are using a map not an image.)

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:imageView];
```

This is equivalent to dragging a UIImageView, with the appropriate image, onto the tableView header in a storyboard.

Please note: The table header view is different from a section header. See [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW32) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^
 {
     //ADD CODES HERE FOR STARTING STATE (FRAME FOR UITABLEVIEW )
    // eg: table.frame=CGRectMake(0,320,320,200);   tableview lying on bottom of viewcontroller with 200px height 

     
 } completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     
    
    // ADD CODES HERE  TO MAKE YOUR FINAL FRAME OF UITABLEVIEW
     // eg: table.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,200);   tableview moving to top of viewcontroller with 200px height


     
 }];
```

Comment: It won't make much difference I'm afraid except that it will move the table with a nice animation and 1.5s is quite a long time.

Comment: it will move uitableview to the top with  slowely if ou want it fast reduce that time

Comment: Appreciate you reading the question once more. I'm not struggling with moving the table but "I want the table not to scroll but to move until a certain point on the screen and then stop moving and start scrolling."

Comment: YES bro here tableview will not scroll ,trust me . it just move the 200px height of tableview from bottom to top .  if you want scroll after animation the in the "completion block" add codes to move to a particular index of tableview