# Resizing UITableView as seen in Rdio iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

Im attempting to replicate the resizing behaviour of a screen seen in the iOS app **Rdio**. The screen in question provides an overview of a selected album and contains a UIView on the top half and a UITableView on the bottom half. When the tableView is scrolled, it first resizes upwards to fill the screen, then begins to scroll through its content normally once the maximum height is reached.

After some searching I found this question: [Dragging UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869795/dragging-uitableview) which is basically asking for the same thing, *however* its accepted method is the same as my initial thoughts & trial, which was to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer and resize the tableviews height according to the translation of the pan.

This does **not** provide the behaviour i'm looking for. Using this method only allows you to statically drag the tableviews height up or down and it has the added issue of the panGesture overriding that of the tableViews which then prevents scrolling through the content.

The resizing behaviour of the Rdio app functions and feels *exactly* like a UIScrollView, it has inertia. You can drag it all the way, flick it up or down, and it smoothly resizes. When the tableView has reached its full-size or original half-size, the remaining inertia is seemingly passed on the tableview causing the cells to scroll as they normally would for that amount. I know they must be manipulating UIScrollViews, I just can't figure out how.

As a final note, eventually I will be using AutoLayout on this screen so i'm wondering how that will potentially hinder or help this situation as well.

**Update**

This approach has gotten me closest to the behaviour i'm looking for so far. 
Flicking the tableView upwards behaves exactly like I wanted it to (resize with inertia & continue scrolling when max height is reached), although with less sensitivity than i'd like. Flicking downwards however, provides no inertia and instantly stops.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scrollViewYOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollViewFrame.origin.y <= kTableViewMaxYOrigin || scrollViewFrame.origin.y <= _originalTableViewFrame.origin.y)
    {
        scrollViewFrame.origin.y -= scrollViewYOffset;

        if(scrollViewFrame.origin.y >= kTableViewMaxYOrigin && scrollViewFrame.origin.y <= _originalTableViewFrame.origin.y)
        {
            scrollViewFrame.size.height += scrollViewYOffset;
            scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame;
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a version that uses autolayout instead. 
It took me a while of trial and error to get this one right!

Please use the comments and ask me if the answer is unclear.

In `viewDidLoad` save the initial height of your layout constraint determining the lowest down you want the scrollview to be.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    _initialTopLayoutConstraintHeight = self.topLayoutConstraint.constant;
    ...
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    BOOL leaveScrollAlone = self.topLayoutConstraint.constant == _initialTopLayoutConstraintHeight && scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0;
    if (leaveScrollAlone)
    {
        // This allows for bounce when swiping your finger downwards and reaching the stopping point
        return;
    }

    // Do some capping of that layout constraint to keep it from going past the range you want it to be.
    // In this case, I use self.topLayoutGuide.length so that my UICollectionView scales all the way until
    // it hits the bottom of the navigation bar
    CGFloat topLayoutConstraintLength =   _initialTopLayoutConstraintHeight - scrollView.contentInset.top;
    topLayoutConstraintLength           = MAX(topLayoutConstraintLength, self.topLayoutGuide.length);
    topLayoutConstraintLength           = MIN(topLayoutConstraintLength, _initialTopLayoutConstraintHeight);
    self.topLayoutConstraint.constant   = topLayoutConstraintLength;


    // Keep content seemingly still while the UICollectionView resizes
    if (topLayoutConstraintLength > self.topLayoutGuide.length)
    {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(scrollView.contentInset.top + scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                                                   scrollView.contentInset.left,
                                                   scrollView.contentInset.bottom,
                                                   scrollView.contentInset.right);

        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }

    // This helps get rid of the extraneous contentInset.top we accumulated for keeping
    // the content static while the UICollectionView resizes
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)
    {
        self.topLayoutConstraint.constant -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;

        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(scrollView.contentInset.top + scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                                                   scrollView.contentInset.left,
                                                   scrollView.contentInset.bottom,
                                                   scrollView.contentInset.right);
    }

    // Prevents strange jittery artifacts
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: I ended up revisiting this mechanic for another app and your auto layout version worked flawlessly. Thank you for contributing it.

Comment: I've used your solution, but it only hides the view on the top of the screen, but UITableView bottom doesn't grow to top. Where can the problem be?

Comment: Hi! It's most likely an issue with the way you have set up the layout constraints. self.topLayoutConstraint Must be a constraint that is attached to the top of the tableview itself. Go into interface builder, and change the size of the constraint to make sure it affects your UITableView

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. What I have is a UIView in the upper half of the screen and a UITableView in the other. Would you mind pointing me out how to set the constraints for both the UITableView and the UIView to get it work, please? 
Guess the problem is there and you pointed me the right way, but I can't figure it out since I'm quite new to autolayouts.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to explain using text: Select your UITableView. Editor>Pin>Top space to superview. This should create the layout constraint you're going to use for the topLayoutConstraint property. Declare the topLayoutConstraint as an outlet, and connect it to the constraint using interface builder.NOTE: You will probably have to pin the UITableView to superview in the leading, trailing and bottom directions too. If this doesn't help, I suggest exploring the AutoLayout system a bit more to get to grips with it... It took me a lot of trial and error to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the key component to getting the smooth inertial resizing in both directions was to update the scrollViews contentInset.top by its contentOffset.y.

I believe this makes sense in retrospect as if the content within is already at the top it cannot scroll anymore, hence the sudden stop rather than smooth scroll. At least thats my understanding.

Another key point was to make sure the cells only started scrolling once maximum or original height was achieved. This was done simply by setting the scrollViews contentOffset to CGPointZero each time the view resized until maximum or original height was reached.

Here is the `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method demonstrating how to achieve this effect.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scrollViewTopContentInset = scrollView.contentInset.top;
    CGFloat scrollViewYOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollViewFrame.origin.y <= kTableViewMaxYOrigin || scrollViewFrame.origin.y <= _originalTableViewFrame.origin.y)
    {
        scrollViewFrame.origin.y -= scrollViewYOffset;

        if(scrollViewFrame.origin.y >= kTableViewMaxYOrigin && scrollViewFrame.origin.y <= _originalTableViewFrame.origin.y)
        {
            scrollViewFrame.size.height += scrollViewYOffset;
            scrollViewTopContentInset += scrollViewYOffset;
            scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame;
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(scrollViewTopContentInset, 0, 0, 0);
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I struggled my whole workday today implementing something like this for my app before I found your answer. Your answer definitely led me in the right direction! 4hrs of twiddling after I saw this I made a version that uses autolayout. Hope it's useful for you in the future if you decide to switch!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the app in question, but from your description... in your `tableView`'s delegate method `-scrollViewDidScroll:`, set `tableView.frame.origin.y` to `albumView.frame.height - tableView.contentOffset.y` and change its height accordingly.

(If you're using autolayout, you'll have to change the constraints pertaining to the tableView's frame rather than the frame itself.)

Comment: Hey @hatfinch I believe you set me on the right path, I've added some new code & explanation to the question showing what i've now implemented. It's still not quite there yet, but a much better result than I was getting before.