# Create Shazam Type UI ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to recreate a UIView I have seen in multiple apps, mainly Shazam. The top half of the screen has some interactive buttons, and the bottom half looks like a tableView with custom cells. When the bottom half is panned/swiped up, the tableView scrolls over the top half with velocity, much like a scroll view.

I have been researching this and experimenting for a couple days now. I have gotten close, but not quite there.

My last approach was a view that had a tableView inside it. When the view was panned, the view would move to wherever the finger moved it to, but then would not have any velocity afterwards. Also when the tableView was panned/swiped down, it wouldn't move the whole view down.

Before that I tried a scrollView that took up the whole length of the screen. That gave the desired effect, but the button wasn’t tappable, and you could scroll the view in the button area, which is undesired.

Does it utilize ScrollViews or is it using a tableView that acts much like a ScrollView somehow.

Here is the Shazam UI/UX I am looking to recreate:
The top portion has interactive buttons, and doesn’t scroll. The bottom half shows content and when scrolled, covers up the top portion.

[image]

Below is what I have tried so far: This one is the panning view, which sort of works, but doesn’t have velocity and the tableView doesn’t scroll the view back down.

[image]

Any thoughts on a direction I can take from here is greatly appreciated. I am using Swift.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869795/dragging-uitableview?
Is in Obj-c but the coding works basically the same

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is perhaps best done with a collection view and a custom layout — you can have some items for which you set layout attributes absolute to the view, and others relative to the scroll content offset.

There's a great (if wandering) discussion of this and other techniques in the [Advanced User Interfaces with Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=232) talk from WWDC 2014.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually simple than it seems at first. Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Create a `UIViewController` (not a `UITableViewController`).
2. Add some buttons to the top area of the screen.
3. Add a table view spanning the entire view controller's view. Make sure the table view is on top of the buttons added in the previous step.
4. Configure the top cell of the table view to be transparent (by setting its background color to Clear). Set the background color on the table view  to Clear as well. This way it won't obscure the elements at the top of the screen, unless the table is scrolled up.
5. Because your table view is now transparent, you'll need to explicitly set the background color on the table cells other than the top one.
6. Profit!

Comment: But how will you handle UI elements touches that are at the top? keeping UITableview in front of them will disable their interaction.